# I have a custom domain in dotcloud, how do i add ssl on the custom domain

Tags: dotcloud

The dotcloud domain works with https, i.e.

```
https://xxxx-username.dotcloud.com/
```

but how do i add that to the custom domain?

```
https://mydomain.com
```

Comment: Beware that you can't use naked domains on dotcloud: http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/domains/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have SSL on your own domain name, you will need to purchase your own SSL certificate, and to upgrade to one of the paying offers (Pro or Enterprise).

Why? Because they will need to dedicate a load balancer instance to your application (since SSL requires at least one IP address per domain, or more accurately, per certificate).

Once you are upgraded to one of the paying plans, you will submit a support ticket letting them know you want a an SSL for a custom domain, and they will let you know what you need to do to get it up and running.

Here is a brief overview of those steps.

Go buy an SSL cert for your domain if you don't already own one.

Make sure you already added the DNS alias for the application you would like the SSL for. http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/domains/

The SSL material will generally be made of two or three parts: 
- the secret key (which should be protected by a passphrase), 
- the certificate (which does not have to be protected, since it contains no sensitive information), 
- an optional "certificate chain" or "intermediate certificates" (this is not always necessary; and when it is, it can be bundled with your certificate, or come as separate files; your certificate authority will supply that if it's needed).

Once you have those files, you need to create a virtual service to transfer them to dotCloud in a secure manner. 
The service should be named "edge.ssl", and of type "python-worker". 
It should contain 2 or 3 files: 
- ssl.key (containing the private key) 
- ssl.crt (containing the certificate) 
- ssl.chain (optional; containing the chain of intermediary certificates)

Once you have pushed this service, tell them and they will go on with the setup of your SSL instance.

Note that this "edge.ssl" does not count against your total number of deployed services. 
It's actually just a convenient and secure way to transfer the SSL material, which will be only available to their infrastructure.

Once they have the SSL certs, they will deploy your own dedicated load balancer and then let you know when it is ready to be used, and what you need to do DNS wise to start using it.

Comment: In other words, it's $100 a month for SSL. Which.is.totally.crazy.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch not anymore, dotCloud just released new pricing. https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing.html